What is the purpose of this monitor having multiple inputs?
Someone gave me this monitor. Tried using each of the three HDMI ports to connect to my MacBook Pro. Did not work. I then purchased a DP to HDMI converter. But, what is the purpose of multiple inputs?
The company, First, seems to be out of business as the website is long gone (checked archive.org).
Any help appreciated.
UPDATE, I forgot to mention: the monitor works perfectly well. I discovered the monitor control panel and switched the input source from DP to HDMI 1. Voila! That allowed me to successfully connect it to my MacBook.


Multiple inputs allow you to connect multiple sources...? Have you tried connecting to one input, and then looking for a button / menu to select which input is to be displayed?

Without the manual, nothing is certain.  However, monitor inputs should be for monitor inputs.  I have never seen an HDMI out on a monitor, which would make sense for HDCP.
If I had to guess, those are inputs, but are broken/damaged.  Maybe that is why your friend gave it to you.

Your question is, what is the purpose of multiple inputs on a monitor?
It is to allow multiple devices to be connected to one monitor. An example would be of having 2 or 3 servers, and connecting them all to one monitor. There should be a button, and on screen menu on the monitor itself that allows you to select the input that it is attempting to display.
A more detailed reson for having multiple devices connected to a single display that can only show one of the connected devices at a time is that one or more of the connected devices is less used for direct interface. A home example would be having something like a PLEX server or a NAS or a Pi device that you don't need to access except when it is not working as expected. Often this function isnt used, as switching display does not switch the input device (i.e. keyboard and mouse), so a device called a KVM switch(keyboard video and mouse) is often used instead of the multiple inputs on the monitor itself.
Most modern monitors auto switch to the active input, but some may not. The inputs may in fact be broken, but as a lower end model, it may not auto sense the active input and require manual change of input with the on screen menu to select alternate inputs.
